# Can I configure gvim to be less sensitive to middle-click-and-drag?

Tags: vim

One of life's little annoyances is that if I middle-click to paste on a gvim window, a single pixel of movement causes a block of text to be highlighted. Not only does this stop the paste but it replaces the current selection buffer so I can't repeat the action straight away.

Is there a way I can configure gvim to ignore movements of less than X pixels when middle-clicking?

(I don't notice this problem elsewhere, so I think it's an application-level issue rather than a window manager issue. I also don't want a wm-specific solution.)

Comment: `"*p` is the same as pasting with middle click (which may be easier to use if middle click is too sensitive)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although that assumes I'm already at the correct cursor position. I'm generally not. So then I have a a left-click-and-drag problem.

Comment: You are supposed to move the cursor with your keyboard, not with your mouse.

Comment: *You* may, I use both. I was asking for help, not ideology.

Comment: You're kind of out of luck: Vim is strong with ideology. The amount of customisation Vim can do is rather broad, but also very limited; if you expect Vim to change to accomodate your habits rather than changing your habits to accomodate Vim, you will never be an effective Vim user. In particular, I am reasonably certain that sensitivity to dragging is not configurable from within Vim.

Comment: I am not sure if mouse events can be mapped with vim but this is something I have used for `copy-drag` sequence. [dragvisual.vim](https://youtu.be/aHm36-na4-4?t=34m11s)